# Accessing parent state in child in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

I have (e.g.) two components in React. The first, `app.js`, is the root component. It imports some `JSON` data and puts it in its `state`. This works fine (I can see it in the React devtools).

```
import data from '../data/docs.json';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      docs: {}
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      docs: data
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Wrapper}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/docs" component={Docs} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The second, `docs.js`, is meant to show this `JSON` data. To do that it needs to access the `state` of `app.js`. At the moment it errors, and I know why (`this` does not include `app.js`). But how then can I pass the `state` from `app.js` to `docs.js`?

```
class Docs extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.docs.map(function(study, key) { 
                    return <p>Random text here</p>; 
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: related - [How to make a shared state between two react components?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38901106/104380)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The proper way of doing this would be by passing state as `props` to `Docs` component.

However, because you are using `React Router` it can be accessed in a bit different way: `this.props.route.param` instead of default `this.props.param`

So your code should look more or less like this:

```
<Route path="/docs" component={Docs} docs={this.state.docs} />
```

and

```
{this.props.route.docs.map(function(study, key) { 
    return <p>Random text here</p>; 
})}
```

Comment: i can't send states all my 20 componentes, there is a way to do it with redux?

Comment: This explained **nothing**. passing it is the easy part, but what then? what is the proper way to extend the child with the state of the parent so they will both share the exact same Object and not a copy of the state in the child?

Comment: @vsync if you will pass parent's state to the child as a prop, it will be the same object.

Comment: it will, at first. but then `setState` will be called somewhere in the child, and then the state of the child will be out-of-sync because of this new thing the new generation of developers loves so much, called immutability. horrid thing. only causes troubles.

Comment: @vsync if you want to share child's state with the parent, you should modify parent's state using callbacks and pass it down using props

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this is:

```
<Route path="/docs" component={() => <Docs docs={this.state.docs}/>}>
```

If you need to pass children:

```
<Route path="/" component={(props) => <Docs docs={this.state.docs}>{props.children}</Docs>}>
```

If you are doing it like this, then you can access your props values directly by `this.props.docs` in Child Component:

```
{
    this.props.docs.map((study, key)=> { 
       return <p key={key}>Random text here</p>; 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this will be

```
        <Route path='/' render={ routeProps => <Home 
            {...routeProps} 
            docs={this.state.docs}
            /> 
          } 
        />
```

While in the child component you can access `docs` using

```
this.props.docs
```

Hope it helps!