# How can I create shared state for HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I have created `LoadBookHOC` which is wrapped with `BookDetails` and `BookSummary` component.

**LoadBookHOC.js**

```
const LoadBookHOC = InnerComponent => class LoadBook extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
       super();
       this.state={
          book: []
       };
    }

    set= obj => this.setState(obj);

    render(){
      return(
         <InnerComponent 
            {...this.props} 
            hocState={this.state} 
            hocSetState={this.set}
         />
      );
    }

}
```

**BookDetails.js**

```
this.hocSetState({book: <new data>});
```

**BookSummary.js**

```
this.hocSetState({book: <new data>});
```

Whenever `this.props.hocState.book` called in `BookDetails` or `BookSummary`, I need to get the same data. I mean all the `InnerComponent` should get the same update. Is there any other way instead of redux (makes use to write lots of code)?

**update**: How can I make this HOC acting like a **provider or context or shared state**? which one is suitable for this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

HOC is not for sharing state , but sharing functionality. If you are having two instances for eg: `<BookDetails/>` and `<BookSummary/>`  in same page , both enhanced with same HOC, there will be two instances of `book array`. So updating in one component wont be visible to other one.

For sharing state you should as you said use Redux or store state in common Parent component.

Comment: How can I create shared state for HOC?