# How to share data between two remote components with one custom hook react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components which are located in different position in the hierarchy. One component has data which should be used in another component. I was trying to achieve this with custom hook. When I used in components I'm getting false, I want it to be true because I set it to true from component 1 so component 2 should get true. I don't know little bit confused on custom hooks.

Custom Hook

```
export const useShareData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const setValue = (value: boolean) => {
    setData(value)
  }
  return [data, setValue]
}
```

Component 1

```
const [data, setData] = useShareData()
const dataToBeShared = true
useEffect(()=>{
   setData(dataToBeShared)
},[dataToBeShared])
```

Component 2

```
const [data] = useShareData()
console.log(data)
```

In component 2 the value is always false.

Comment: Try using context

Comment: Cannot use context because there are many components between them don't want to use it, I'm trying to achieve with custom hook

Comment: I think there only three ways mostly used, lift the state, context and external package like redux , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451584/is-it-possible-to-share-states-between-components-using-the-usestate-hook-in-r or else you can use useGlobalState https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-global-state, try it

Comment: `Cannot use context because there are many components between them don't want to use it` I don't understand. That's exactly what context is good for: skipping intermediate components that don't want to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a custom hook doesn't let data be shared, it just lets *code* be shared.  While component 1 is rendering, if it calls `const [data, setData] = useState<boolean>(false)`, it creates a state variable for component 1. This is the case whether it's written inline or extracted to a helper function (aka, a custom hook). Similarly, when component 2 calls useState, it creates state for component 2. The two states are not shared.

The standard approach for your issue is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to whatever component is the common ancestor of these two components, and then pass it down. If the common ancestor is nearby, props can be used; if it's far away, [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) becomes a more attractive option.