# What is the canonical React-Redux method to pass elements/references between atomic components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm trying to abstract a portion of [this](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#PrimarySearchAppBar.tsx) example from using local React hooks to storing the information in Redux.

In particular, the [Popover menu](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/) requires `anchorEl` to be specified in order to anchor to a parent `<HTMLElement>` for positioning. The above example from MaterialUI implements the `useState` hook to store and change this property:

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
```

When I try to convert this to Redux,

```
dispatch(accountMenuSlice.actions.setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget));
```

it ends up trying to store non-serializable `<HTMLElement>`, which [is not advisable](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1793), yielding the following warning/error

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2430 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`. 
Value: <button>​…​</button>​ 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  
{type: "ACCOUNT_MENU_KEY/setAnchorEl", payload: button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-colorInherit.MuiIconButton-edgeEnd}
```

What is the canonical React-Redux method to pass elements/references between atomic components without [elevating abstractions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53455474/12728698) into parent components?

Comment: You mean "canonical" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making the popover a child of the button and it went pretty cleanly:

```
// AccountButton.tsx
export default function AccountButton() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleAccountMenuOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton
        edge="end"
        aria-label="account of current user"
        aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleAccountMenuOpen}
        color="inherit"
      >
        <AccountCircle />
      </IconButton>
      <AccountMenu anchorEl={anchorEl} setAnchorEl={setAnchorEl} />
    </>
  );
}
```

and

```
// AccountMenu.tsx
export default function AccountMenu(props: {
  anchorEl: HTMLElement;
  setAnchorEl: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HTMLElement>>;
}) {
  const { anchorEl, setAnchorEl } = props;
...
}
```