# ReactJs change text upon button click problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a large project with multiple files. I want a button to render the content of some other components upon clicking. I am trying to understand why the following does not work, and what could I do to make it work instead?

#### Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { unitState, setUnitState } from './changeUnit.js'


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{unitState}</h1>

      <button onClick={setUnitState("°C")}>°C</button>
      <button onClick={setUnitState("°F")}>°F</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// ------
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

#### changeUnit.js

```
export let unitState = "°C";
export function setUnitState(unit) {
    (unit==="°C") ? unitState="°C" : unitState="°F";
}
```

### with [codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/changeunitstate-xtbny?file=/src/index.js)

---

Currently, upon clicking any of the buttons the text does not change. But the code does reach inside the `setUnitState` method. I suspect that is because the main component is not rerendering. I tried to change my `changeUnit.js` code to

```
import App from './index.js';

export let unitState = "°C";
export function setUnitState(unit) {
    (unit==="°C") ? unitState="°C" : unitState="°F";
    App.forceUpdate();
}
```

but I get the error `_index.default.update is not a method`.

I have tried to use the `useState` hook from React but I just can't make it work for the life of me. I have tried many combinations but it seems that I can't return the `setState` function as a return from the custom hook.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What's the problem with useState?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're not using the `useState` hook, or what went wrong with your custom hook.

With `useState()`:

```js
function App() {
  let [unitState, setUnitState] = React.useState('°C')
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{unitState}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setUnitState('°C')}>°C</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnitState('°F')}>°F</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

With custom hook:

```js
function App() {
  let { unitState, setCelsius, setFahrenheit } = useSwitch()
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{unitState}</h1>
      <button onClick={setCelsius}>°C</button>
      <button onClick={setFahrenheit}>°F</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function useSwitch() {
  let [unitState, setUnitState] = React.useState('°C')
  let setCelsius = () => setUnitState('°C')
  let setFahrenheit = () => setUnitState('°F')
  return { unitState, setCelsius, setFahrenheit }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But say I have another file `component.js` where the `<h1>{unitState}</h1>` is present. How to I pass it the `unitState` value ? Do I have to call again `let { unitState, setCelsius, setFahrenheit } = useSwitch()` because that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, you'll either need to lift the state or use context. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451584/is-it-possible-to-share-states-between-components-using-the-usestate-hook-in-r

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you probaly weren't using `useState` right. this is fairly simple with use state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// import { unitState, setUnitState } from "./changeUnit.js";

function App() {
  const [unitState, setUnitState] = useState("°C");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{unitState}</h1>

      <button onClick={() => setUnitState("°C")}>°C</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnitState("°F")}>°F</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// ------
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just use setState, it might be the case that you were trying to call the setState without the lambda?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [unitState, setUnitState] = useState("C");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{unitState}</h1>

      <button onClick={() => setUnitState("C")}>C</button>
      <button onClick={() => setUnitState("F")}>F</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// ------
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/changeunitstate-forked-zbrym