# Why my state's are not getting shared in an example implemented using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react.js,

What I am trying to achieve is how to share states between two Components.

I have created 'MainComponent', which renders 'FirstComponent' and 'SecondComponent'.

FirstComponent renders a input text. And SecondComponent renders paragraph diplaying data.

What I need is,

If any data entered in FirstComponent should be rendered in SecondComponent.

My code is as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React Demo 01</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> <!-- This tag is required or else babel gives regex error -->
    <script src="../../lib/react.development.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>       
    <script src="../../lib/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="../../lib/babel.min.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>React DEMO 01</h1>
    <div id="example"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        function Store(){
            var intialState = new Object();
            this.state = intialState;
        }

        Store.prototype.mergeState = function(partialState){
            Object.assign(this.state,partialState);
        }

        var myStore = new Store();

        class SecondComponent extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);                   
            }

            render(){
                return (<div>
                            <p>{this.props.someThing}</p>
                        </div>)
            }
        }

        class FirstComponent extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.handleTxt = this.handleTxt.bind(this);
            }

            handleTxt(event){
                console.log(event.target.value);
                this.props.mergeState({
                    "someThing" : event.target.value
                });
            }

            render(){
                return (<div>
                            <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleTxt} />
                        </div>)
            }
        }

        class MainComponent extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
            }

            render(){
                return (
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><FirstComponent mergeState={myStore.mergeState.bind(myStore)} /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><SecondComponent mergeState={myStore.mergeState.bind(myStore)} /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                )
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />,document.getElementById("example"));
    </script>
</body>
```

From the above example you see
'FirstComponent' renders input text, an 'onKeyPress' event is attached which captures the input data and set it in shared state.

```
class FirstComponent extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.handleTxt = this.handleTxt.bind(this);
            }

            handleTxt(event){
                console.log(event.target.value);
                this.props.mergeState({
                    "someThing" : event.target.value
                });
            }

            render(){
                return (<div>
                            <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleTxt} />
                        </div>)
            }
        }
```

I need my 'SecondComponent' to capture the shared state and display it.
The code of 'SecondComponent' is as follows

```
class SecondComponent extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);                   
            }

            render(){
                return (<div>
                            <p>{this.props.someThing}</p>
                        </div>)
            }
        }
```

How can I achieve this ?

Is my approach wrong ?

I referred 
[Share Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901106/how-to-make-a-shared-state-between-two-react-components) This link for my example.

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking into hooks. Your mergeStore function is quite hacky.

Comment: @FrankerZ : Can you please give me some more information, I am still struggling